# Error generating zip file error while uploading lambda functions with lambda deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

I have lambda functions folder structure as

```
    ---root
         -functions
           ---node_nodules
           ---lib
           ---function1.js
           ---function2.js
         -function1.lambda
         -function2.lambda
```

There are lot of functions and lot of lambda handler.

The file size of the functions folder is about 140mb due to node modules alone 138 MB.
Though I was able to deploy the lambda function with

```
  lambda deploy function1.lambda.
```

But suddenly following error started to appear.

```
  Error generating zip file
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-lambda/lib/main.js:82
                    throw err;
                    ^

 RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded
at Socket.onChildStdout (child_process.js:354:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:13)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

I tried searching for the fix, but i could not find any appropriate one. Can anyone help here ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest to take a small detour to get *The Serverless Framework* [here](https://www.serverless.com) installed and let it package & deploy your Lambda. For an example, refer [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/examples/hello-world/node/).

It is going to be way lot easier, as it manages packaging ZIPs, deploying to AWS including downloading latest NPM modules before packaging and cleaning up etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try and let you know.

Comment: Well, that's very handy package for developing a new server-less functions, but i have a lot of functions already, do you think its possible to shit from  old way to this one ?